# Timesheet Program to Track Days/Hours worked?

Tags: python

Say I make a program that keeps track of the days I worked and the hours I worked, would I use a dictionary? And how would I differentiate from a Monday on week 1 from a Monday on week 2? How do I get it to store this information after I close the program? (Python Language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is a good way to store the data while your program is running.

There are a number of ways to add some data permanence (so it's around after you close the program).  The Python modules pickle and [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) are useful and easy to use.  One issue with these is that you can't easily inspect the data outside of a Python program.  There are also modules to read and write text files in the [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and XML formats, and JSON is particularly easy to read in a text editor.  If you aren't already proficient, the databases like MySQL are way more than you need for a personal program like you mention and unless you want to invest some time into learning how to use them, you should go with a simpler solution.

As for the Monday on week 1 vs week 2, you have many options.  You could use the actual date (this seems like a good idea to me), or you could key the dictionary with tuples, like ("Monday", 1).  The main rule is that dictionary keys must be immutable (ints, strings, tuples -- that contain only immutable objects, etc), but not (dictionaries, lists, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a timesheet object for each week, or pay period. Each timesheet object might have a collection of days, with hours worked or times clocked in and out.

For persistent storage for a web site, I'd use a database like mysql. For an application running on a single machine I'd maybe use pickle, or a flat file system maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I took the opposite approach when designing this application for my own use.

In my experience, the biggest problem with timekeeping applications is data entry.  So I decided to make my app use the simplest and most flexible data entry tool available:  a text editor.  I keep notes in a text file and intermingle timekeeping entries in them, so an excerpt looks like this:

```
Monday 5/10/09

release script ok this week
open a case on the whole code-table-foreign-key thing

- CUS1 2.0 Generate and release version 1.0.45.

need to get dma to spec out the RESPRB configuration, see case 810
MH section complete - one to go!

- CUS2 4.0 Configure and test Mental Health section.

Tuesday 5/11/09

... and so on
```

I'm consistent in starting each day with the proper heading, and the format of actual timekeeping entries, as you can see, is pretty simple.  A simple scanner and state machine  is all it takes to extract the data - basically, I just look for lines that begin with a weekday or a hyphen, and ignore everything else.

So that the program doesn't get too slow when parsing the notes files, I create a new notes file every year.  (Even at the end of December the parsing process doesn't take more than 1/16 of a second.)

I wouldn't do it this way if I had to process hundreds of peoples' timekeeping entries, because the user does have to have a bit of a clue, and the parsing time would begin to add up after a while.  On the other hand, keeping this data in a human-readable text file that I can store other stuff in (and keep under version control, and diff, and so on) is just incredibly useful.